# The [advice] tag seems like a meta tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is there a single question where adding [advice](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice) is helpful? Remove and block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good point - most everything we answer is advice.

Looking through the list of questions bearing this tag, it adds nothing.

I would delete the tag, but will wait a week for other comments.